# Sending Notifications to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, wcf

I have a HTML5/JavaScript web app that interacts with a WCF RESTful Service.

What I need is some way to update the HTML/JS WebApp UI when something changes on the server machine.

I have looked into Windows Notification Services but it seems this only works for Windows 8 Apps and Windwos Phone Notifications.

Is there a standard / well supported way of doing this?

EDIT: To clarify I am looking for a Real Time push service that I can consume via JS.

Comment: To clarify - are you looking for a real time push service?

Comment: Yes I am, Thanks for helping me clarify that Ryan, I have edited my original post to make that more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look at: http://signalr.net/

this is built exactly for your problem. Please note your server needs to allow websockets as far as i remember.

EDIT: [EXAMPLE](http://callumhibbert.blogspot.nl/2012/02/minimal-signalr-example_08.html)

Comment: +1 for Signalr - we use this for a real-time server health monitoring app and it's awesome. Don't think it strictly needs WebSockets as it falls back to long polling and other methods I believe?

Comment: I's possible, I know about because coworkers used it in a project :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at http://pusher.com , I think that is exactly what you need.

HTH